# Audio Diagnostic Tool for Ubuntu Studio

Tags: sound, ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 (with the extra App Backport to get LTS).

I wonder if there is some audio diagnostic (and repair) tool for Ubuntu Studio...

Where? How?

It is intended to fix some weird audio behaviour in one of my desktop PC, behaviour not present in the other PCs I have with the same Operating System and apps.

Comment: I think you should ask about the problem itself instead of about a diagnostic tool that AFAIK doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, Gabriela! It is a real pity that there is not some kind of tools to test the hardware and drivers performance in Ubuntu. Well, I have to ask this, in your way. Thanks a lot!